# Sql to linq convention

Tags: linq

i have a problem to build my linq query and i need you help , the following code is what i have got so far
, it does has some errors as expected, so, this is my sql query :

*im new to linq and did searched over google.

```
select CAST(h.changedate as date) as 'RegDate' ,count (cast(h.changedate as date)) as 'Amount' from T_TalmidStatusHistory h
    join T_talmid t on h.talmidid = t.talmidid 
    where t.talmidStatusID=16 and h.[statusid] != 16
        and h.id =
            (
                select max(id) from T_TalmidStatusHistory 
                    where T_TalmidStatusHistory.talmidid=h.talmidid  and T_TalmidStatusHistory.[statusid] != 16
            )
    group by CAST(h.changedate as date)
```

and this is what i have right now in linq:

```
    var res = from r in db.T_TalmidStatusHistories
              from m in db.T_TalmidStatusHistories
   join t in db.T_Talmids  on r.TalmidID equals t.TalmidID
   where  t.TalmidStatusID == 16 && r.StatusID != 16
    && r.id == from l in db.T_TalmidStatusHistories
        where m.TalmidID  == r.TalmidID && m.StatusID != 16
        select new{db.T_TalmidStatusHistories.OrderByDescending(tp => tp.id).FirstOrDefault().id }
        group h by h.changedate as date
   select new { h.changedate as date, count (cast(h.changedate as date))};
```

Edit:
i'm expecting to get the number of students that sign up on each date,

my error is :
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
at line : r.id == from l in db.T_TalmidStatusHistories

ty.

Comment: It could help if you show some sample data and result expected

Comment: Clarify scheme of tables on sql server side, please.

Answer (score 0):

The whole part

```
from l in db.T_TalmidStatusHistories ... count (cast(h.changedate as date))}
```

is one query which is compared to `r.id` by the `==` operator.

Change it to

```
...
r.id == (db.T_TalmidStatusHistories
        .Where(m.TalmidID  == r.TalmidID && m.StatusID != 16)
        .OrderByDescending(tp => tp.id).FirstOrDefault().id)
group h by h.changedate as date
select new { h.changedate as date, count (cast(h.changedate as date))};
```